# Has the Cthulhu chat egg (and the other ones) been removed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, easter-eggs

As some of you may know, there was an Easter egg available in the chat called "the Cthulhu Egg".
In an homage to the old ["How to parse Html with RegEx"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1005187) answer, sending a chat message with a fitting reg expression would display some random quotes from the answer all floating over the screen.

In the hope of finding a nice Cthulhu Hat, I just tried the egg today (winter bash style), but it didn't seem to work anymore.

Now I am asking: do anyone know if it has been removed? I used to remember it working on all the main chat sites... has it been restricted to some specific ones??

Edit: I forgot the standard Winter Bash Haiku:

Great Cthulhu sleeping
Waiting for the summoning
Winter snow falling

Comment: `insert coin` seems to have gone as well D:

Comment: All of the chat easter eggs appear to be missing

Comment: Also missing: Clippy, from SU, and rm -rf from SF.

Comment: I hope this is not a choice between hats and easter eggs. That is a monstrous thing to inflict on people.

Comment: If that was the case, we will get them back after the bash ends. Anyway... I was really looking forward to a octopus hat for triggering the egg.

Comment: Not all eggs are broken, [search easter egg](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=easter+egg&room=17) still working. Guess when they added hat support they removed the eggs, either by mistake or by design. (conflict maybe?)

Comment: Anyway, [other easter egg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoK32JvHz6M) didn't give me any hat when doing it. Guess eggs and hats don't like each other! :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard - you could always help me deobfuscate the script on the bash site. Maybe there is something hidden there.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist you mean JavaScript in the winterbash homepage?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yes, the last year by holding ctrl and moving the mouse around you could gather the falling snow. Gather enough and a unicorn appeared. I am still looking at the script to find out if there is something similar this year.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, that was a bug. The main chat JavaScript finds the location from where it should load the easter egg JavaScript by looking at its own location, and for that it needs to find itself by name. But for WinterBash, the JS filename has changed, thus couldn't be found, and no eggs were loaded. This is fixed now (needs a page refresh)