# A Yaakov Ellis-inspired Meta.SE poetry contest: Write poems, win rep!

Tags: discussion, fun

> ### Update July 9, 2020
>
> **Submissions are now closed.** Thanks everyone who participated; the bounties will be awarded soon!

---

> Yaakov Ellis
> Posting answers as haikus
> Poetry contest

---

I'm sure that at least some of you have seen Yaakov Ellis's recent [haiku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32877/295232) answers. If not, here are some examples: [(1)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348883/294691), [(2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348816/294691), [(3)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348523/294691).

In that spirit, I also posted a [bug report entirely in limerick form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349511/294691) (with a bit of editing from @ArtOfCode).

And then... I had an idea. Especially as we're in the middle of the Stack company [community-a-thon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348271/294691), why not have a bit of light-hearted fun, encourage Meta.SE participation, and honor the poetic efforts of our hard-working dev?

So here's the deal.

From **June 18, 2020** to <s>July 2, 2020</s> **July 9, 2020** (allowing a bit of wobbliness for timezones), you can submit your poem as an entry into this contest by posting your poem as an answer to this Meta.SE question.
This can be any type of poetry - haikus, limericks, sonnets, freeform - but **it has to be an *original* poem**.

Your poem must be **Meta.SE themed**, and ideally should meet all the requirements of whatever form of poem you've chosen (including syllable count, meter, and rhyme scheme).

You can submit **any number of entries** into this contest.

In-jokes and meme references are more than welcome (although an explanatory link might be a good thing to include).

At the end of the contest, **at least 4,000 reputation in bounties**<sup>1</sup> will be awarded to the best entries (personal favorites and influenced by votes on the submissions), spread out across multiple posts. (How exactly it gets divided still remains to be seen, depending on how many submissions there are.) However, **I will only be awarding bounties to those with under 40,000 total Meta.SE reputation**. People who have more reputation than that can still participate, just not be eligible to win a bounty.

(**Update June 23, 2020**: After some consideration (and noting the relatively low participation), I've removed the requirement that an entry must be a poem in its own separate Meta.SE post and instead specified that it must be Meta.SE *themed* (and extended the deadline by a week). It's a bit much to ask for people to write an entirely separate Meta.SE post; instead, you can simply submit your Meta.SE-themed poem here on this question. (Entries that meet the previous requirements still count, though!<sup>2</sup>))

---

> Rules all specified
> Contest ready to begin
> Everyone have fun!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>By myself, @ArtOfCode, @Aibobot, and @rene.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>**Note**: If you *are* submitting a separate post as a poem, in most cases, it's best if the content is not *exclusively* a poem, especially if it's a long post. If you're writing something in poetic form, if the content is important *please* make sure to include a plain English version as well.</sub>

Comment: +1 for knowing that my first name, when properly pronounced, has three syllables

Comment: There once was a question by Mithical; Who had an idea quite whimsical; They decided a contest; To find who was funnest; And with it a gift rather mystical.

Comment: Should just the link be submitted? Or the poem copied in as well?

Comment: I would use a thank-you reaction on this post if I was able to

Comment: @YaakovEllis - Doesn't hurt to put the poem in as well.

Comment: Posts in the Sandbox – don't count as regular ones – I guess, or do they?

Comment: @Glorfindel Unfortunately / they do not count in this case / isn't regular. It has to be an actual MSE post.

Comment: That is a funny coincidence for me. [I just replied to some meta.stackoverflow.com limericks with haiku](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398419/3404097).

Comment: Go on - I'll throw in an extra 1k reputation in bounties

Comment: Is there a requirement that poems must scan correctly, or otherwise correctly fit the pattern of their type of poetry?

Comment: @ArtOfCode - While technically you can claim that it's freeform if the scansion is off, let's just say that if it's failed it is unlikely to win. :)

Comment: This should be featured, spread some joy :)

Comment: As I'm technically ruled out to win I'll throw in 1k of my reputation as well.

Comment: You might want to recommend that people submitting these include a small link (even add the markdown for adding a sub 1 note) pointing to this contest within their answer, This would avoid people thinking an answer was being given in a sardonic manner (and spread the word more as a bonus)

Comment: I'm in for 1k, just to confirm :D

Comment: Since the competition does not accept edit comments, here is just a [honourable entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/349606/2).

Comment: Am I mistaken or technically none of the answers posted so far actually qualifies for the specified rules of this contest? Not that this is a real problem since after all this is an unofficial contest, but you may want to clarify this to avoid possible flames later. Just my two cents there.

Comment: @Blue - They're all poems that were posted elsewhere on Meta.SE, and each of them contains a link to the original post. Seems to count.

Comment: Duplicate questions or answers to duplicate questions aren't considered as well. Right?

Comment: @GarimanSingh - Correct; those would fall under the "closed" exclusion

Comment: Is it within bounds to extract the poetry form from another, full answer on another site, combined with related off-site verses?

Comment: @User777088 - if it's not about MSE, it doesn't count

Comment: Nope, it's about MSO. :(

Comment: [Contest is over / 
Results are to be announced / 
I am excited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350626/771581)

Comment: (Figuring out awarding with the other people who pledged rep. Stay tuned!)

Comment: I don't see the bounty button. Why is it not possible to have two bounties contemporarily but by two different users? I would like to offer 200 rep to Simona.

Comment: @marilou it's because of the way that we record the active bounty in the db - only permits one on a time per question. Allowing for multiple bounties at the same time would require rearchitecting things. Would be simpler to allow a bounty to reward an existing question to go through right away, without 24h period, but that would still be a bunch of work.

Comment: Voting to leave this open. Yes, the competition is closed, but you can't put bounties on closed questions ...

Answer (score 31):

[My sonnet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349562/51):

> A user thought to pay a just reward,
> by adding bounty payment on a post,
> and after setting what they could afford,
> they clicked start and sent it on to the host.
> Now off to share the link with Tavern crowd,
> did Mithical set out at once with glee,
> and what they saw made them stop feeling proud,
> 'cause printed there was four instead of three.
> Quick on to Meta to report the case,
> came our brave hero armed with prose and rhyme,
> thus when I saw it — turned red in my face,
> and sought to repro' and fix in no time.
> I now announce the squashing of the bug,
> it's now forgotten — swept under the rug.

Comment: (A bounty worth 500 reputation will be awarded on [the other answer where this was posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349562/294691).)

Answer (score 23):

> 'Twas crinkling, and the regulars
>    on Meta Tavern squawked and typed;
> About some new particulars
>    For which no one was hyped.
>
> Why was the tooltip changed so fast,
>    and there was no discussion had?
> We thought that this was in the past,
>    is clarity a fad?
>
> The brouhaha gained speed and steam
>    with many users chiming in:
> What happened to the CM team?
>    Do they not hear the din?
>
> After an hour and maybe more
>    [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349800/794227) posted quite sincere:
> We must improve the process of yore
>    to make these things more clear.
>
> Reverted has the tooltip been,
>    moar research is required here.
> And when a change is made again
>    we'll publicize, no fear!
>
> And so on MSE they saw:
>    Though now and then mistakes are made;
> This is no sign of fatal flaw,
>    good feelings will not fade.
>
> 'Twas crinkling, and the regulars
>    on Meta Tavern sat back down,
> because from new particulars -
>    a smile made out of frown

<sub>(Inspired by [Jabberwocky](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42916/jabberwocky), which appears to be in 8-8-8-6 meter for the most part with an ABAB rhyme scheme. "moar" spelling intentional)</sub>

Comment: I enjoyed your poem, it's one of the few that rhymes, but not only, it's clever and it's really about MSE community. Worthy of a bounty, fear not Simona. You have an admirer here.

Comment: Its in the list. The logistics of bounty awarding is messy, so it might take a while for us to get around to it ;)

Answer (score 15):

> This user came with a just doubt,
> "What if I lose my hard-earned
> reputation out?"
>
> They wanted some attention to their
> question nice,
> So decided to pay a
> 50 reputation price.
>
> There seemed just a single limitation,
> Afraid they were to lose on other
> sites their reputation.
>
> But such is not the case,
> One is not charged at another place.
>
> They may move ahead with this generous deed,
> And pay this confusion no
> heed.

This is the short poem I posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349603/771581).

Comment: At last, I write typical a [haiku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350626/771581), / 
And express bright Mithical a "Thank You!"

Comment: (A bounty worth 300 reputation will be awarded on [the other answer where this was posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349603/294691).)

Answer (score 13):

[My poem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349554/707129):

> I recently came across a post
>
> And I said to myself holy ghost
>
> It's mine, that's Daniil
>
> But then I stood still
>
> Why vote for myself? I never boast

Answer (score 10):

[A haiku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349606)

> Tooltip is zealous
> in promoting temperance.
> It is frustrating.

Answer (score 10):

A haiku from [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349634/188189) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349632/sns-stackexchange)

> Web applications
> yes we have a site for them
> find your answers there

Answer (score 9):

I remember posting haiku on at least three (quite old now) posts before: [first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash), [second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227700/171199) and [third](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212347/has-the-cthulhu-chat-egg-and-the-other-ones-been-removed). Having to chose, I think the first one is probably the best one in the set, if anything because I actually tried to make it work when translated to Japanese.

```
ユニコーン (は)
雪にきらめく
(の) 冬の兆候

Yunikōn (wa)
yuki ni kirameku
(no) fuyu no chōkō

The Unicorn
glittering in snows
sign of winter
```

This haiku was written as a reference to the old 2012 Winter Bash site easter egg.

[image]

To actually fit the 5-7-5 "on" requirement, you have to drop the two particles "wa" and "no" on the first and third verse, which in turn makes the wording far less "grammatically correct" I fear. At least it somehow match the "Kigo" requirement in a way - there is a "seasonal reference" in the poem, but it only makes sense as a Meta-specific seasonal reference.

Back when I wrote this, Winter Bash always ended up making a reference to unicorns in a way or the other, so you could say "unicorns" were a sign of Winter in a way.

Comment: A bounty worth 300 reputation will be awarded on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335654/294691).

Comment: I'm aware - it's just a (relatively) recent answer of yours since the bounty can't be awarded on this post (due to requirements for increasing bounty size)

Answer (score 9):

For those moderating the C and C++ tags at SO:

> What is the result
> iplusplus plus iplusplus
> Endlessly we ask

> The unspecified
> evaluation order
> Only half the truth

> Trying to explain
> Behaviour undefined
> Outcome is unknown

> A long-winded speech
> Of some abstract sequence points
> Wasted on deaf ears

> Close as duplicate
> Over and over again
> Pointless busy-work done

Comment: Most vexing poetry:(

Answer (score 9):

I know that the contest is closed, but I feel like I still have to post [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358638/can-you-help-a-poor-unicorn-to-find-its-way-back-home) here anyway:

> Once upon a Wint Bash morrow, while I pondered, full of sorrow
> Over endless db rows recording stats of games galore —
> While I tried, nearly succeeding, to prevent the mounds of cheating
> Suddenly there came a vision, pinging on my chatroom door —
> “What could that be,” I muttered, “blinking on my chatroom door —
>    Only this and nothing more.”
>
> And the silken, bright, and forlorn fur of our fave-rit unicorn
> Thrilled me — filled me with a fantastic hope that I had not felt before;
> And I thought: “Avast the fearing, soon there will be so much cheering,
> When our hero, bold and mighty, shows distinction on the quizzing floor;
> Will it be you, who can help our 'corn find its way to succor?
>    Only this and nothing more.”

Answer (score 7):

Made a [(now closed) bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349781/622284), and figured I'd use a bit of a different format. I chose a [Haiku Sonnet](https://www.writersdigest.com/write-better-poetry/haiku-sonnet-poetic-form), which is a series of 4 haiku followed by a couplet with either 5 or 7 syllables for either line.

Although the bug report's now closed, it appears that that doesn't break the rules of the contest anymore.

Hope you enjoy.

> "Others with this badge,"
> Has issues with its spacing
> And its alignment

> With names, long displayed,
> The list item appears wrong,
> And might need some work

> With names like Shog9,
> There's not a visual bug,
> And it renders fine

> But, others are long
> Shadow Wizard Wearing Mask
> Throws alignment off

> Could this please be looked into,
> Perhaps tagged [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)?

Answer (score 6):

[Comment lock does not prevent automatic duplicate comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349646/336163)

> [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/6471538) comment locked
>
> Autodupe [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction#comment776522_398367) [later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398367/timeline)
>
> Is this intended?

Answer (score 5):

My first attempt at creating [a haiku](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349624/could-the-15-rep-voting-information-text-be-made-clearer)

> Edit I saw done
> Left in state of confusion
> To meta I turned

Answer (score 3):

> Max Muscle Keto
>
> A cry from an outsider
>
> Snuffed - post has been nuked!

Answer (score 3):

A haiku to mark the end of the contest:

> Contest is over
> Results are to be announced
> I am excited

Comment: Thank you @Mithical for such a wonderful contest.

Answer (score 2):

> Browser becalmed,
>
> Not one octet stirrs the wires,
>
> I hate PHP.

> Noob C bean counter,
>
> fails to declare enough space,
>
> missing NUL at end*$.04..bnNy&KCx??......??}}4500spreeyciv..?>||")^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/admin.php

Answer (score 1):

What with the change of rules I suppose I can finally post my (updated) limerick as an answer:

> There once was a question from Mithical
>
> Who had an idea; quite whimsical
>
> A contest, played globally
>
> With the topic of poetry
>
> And the prize; a gift rather mystical.

---

The original for posterity, changed because I wasn't a fan of the poor rhyming of contest/funnest.

> There once was a question by Mithical
>
> Who had an idea; quite whimsical
>
> They decided a contest
>
> To find who was funnest
>
> And with it a gift rather mystical.

Answer (score 1):

Non-competing entry in my answer [Has activity on the site slowed down since COVID-19?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350204/295232), accompanied by a nice illustration:

> Activity grew,
> looking at the question count
> on Stack Overflow