# If I set a bounty, will my reputation be deducted from that Stack Exchange site only?

Tags: support, bounties

I had got 100 reputation bonus on all Stack Exchange sites as association bonus. I need to set a 50 bounty on a question on the *[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site. I understand my reputation will be deducted only from the 101 reputation I have on the Biology Stack Exchange site. Is this correct?

Comment: All sites (and meta-sites) maintain a separate reputation score for actions on that site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the bounty placed on a question on a SE site is deducted from the reputation of the user offering the bounty on that specific site only.

For more details about how the bounty system works you may visit *[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/771581)*.

Here are the problem and the answer summarised in a short poem:

> This user came with a just doubt,
> "What if I lose my hard-earned
> reputation out?"
>
> They wanted some attention to their
> question nice,
> So decided to pay a
> 50 reputation price.
>
> There seemed just a single limitation,
> Afraid they were to lose on other
> sites their reputation.
>
> But such is not the case,
> One is not charged at another place.
>
> They may move ahead with this generous deed,
> And pay this confusion no
> heed.

This is for the post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349555/771581).