# SNS Stack Exchange

Tags: support, site-recommendation, social-networking

Is there a Stack Exchange site that deals with specific questions about [SNSs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/SNS#Noun) e.g. Facebook or Instagram?

Questions like

> How can I batch unfollow multiple people?

> If I unfollow him/her, does he/she know it in real-time?

Answer (score 5):

Social Networking Services are examples of [web-applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) i.e. web sites that look like applications. We have a site for them that has [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) and [instagram](/questions/tagged/instagram) tags.

You can see what kind of questions you can ask on that site [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Web applications
> yes we have a site for them
> find your answers there

Comment: That is the problem with TLAs that are not introduced: *"[SNS. (plural SNSs) 1. (Internet) Initialism of social networking site.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/SNS#Noun)"*

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). They seem to cover social media sites.