# Comment lock does not prevent automatic duplicate comments

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments, comment-lock

> [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/6471538) comment locked
>
> Autodupe [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction#comment776522_398367) [later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/398367/timeline)
>
> Is this intended?

Comment: As long as the comment cannot be edited, it seems by design to me.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @Sonic but we can edit the comment, we always could. Who told you we can't edit? There might be a pending request to disable editing automatic comments, but it was never done.