# Has activity on the site slowed down since COVID-19?

Tags: discussion, statistics, traffic

I’m curious insofar as Stack Overflow being a very rough proxy for how much people are working.

Has site activity gone down since COVID-19?

Are there any interesting patterns in the data (e.g. certain topics trending up, others down)?

Comment: I think the ***complete opposite*** has happened now that we're stuck indoors. And the pattern would not be interesting if you looked at a chart, because a popularity bump-up is exactly what we are expecting.

Comment: @mindstormsboi it appears so! I had suspected stack overflow would have gone down, and sites more 'hobbiest' in nature may have increased. But it does not appear to be true: stack overflow has clearly increased. Although other sites may have decreased (or not increased by as much as they typically would after the quiet Dec/Jan period)

Answer (score 7):

> Activity grew,
> looking at the question count
> on Stack Overflow

[image]

[source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1120804/questions-per-day-n-day-moving-average?numberOfDays=6&fromDate=2020-01-01#graph)

Comment: Interesting. [su] has peaked and dropped back to original levels. See my answer.

Comment: Great research. Important to note there is a massive drop in activity around the end Dec each year, but the increase in activity since COVID-19 is still very evident (if not more so) when your plot starts at 2019-01-01 (rather than at 2020-01-01)

Comment: Does anyone know if similar plots are generated anywhere (some sort of stats summary page perhaps?), especially on a 'per tag' basis (perhaps for the top 100 tags)? I am very curious to see if the upward trend is consistent across all tags. I guess the query could be adapted and run manually for each tag, just wondering if that (or similar) already exists somewhere

Comment: @stevec not that I know of, but it should not be too hard. My query isn't the best point to start; note that it includes deleted questions and no tag information is kept for those in SEDE.

Answer (score 4):

Activity on Super User does not follow the same trend as Stack Overflow:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have the query handy for this? It would be interesting to look at other sites too

Comment: @stevec I used mod stats to get the graphs. Glorfindel's answer has a link to a query that you can change to different sites.

Comment: Ask Different has the same trend; 6-8 weeks of increased activity but it's back to pre-Covid-19 levels.

Comment: @Glorfindel very interesting. I wonder if people had more time at home and used that to investigate various things that had been on their 'to do' lists, but after that (6-8) weeks, they returned to normal usage patterns.